# Cloud SQL socket open failed with error: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Django app on App Engine that connects to a Cloud Sql server.

Recently, some of the requests started to raise the following error from `MySQLdb`:

```
OperationalError: (2062, 'Cloud SQL socket open failed with error: No such file or directory')
```

The error is raised sporadically so it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10118#c20).

Stating from GAE 1.9.5, the number of concurrent db request **per instance** is [limited to 12](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/). The solution was to limit the number of concurrent requests per instance to 12, by changing `app.yaml`:

```
automatic_scaling:
  max_concurrent_requests: 12
```

For those who don't use GAE Modules or Automatic Scaling, the solution may be to disable concurrent requests completely by setting `threadsafe: false`. Note that this might dramatically increase the number of instances.

Another solution is to use some kind of a DB connection pool with a limited number of simultaneous connections. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I don't see how this can be a solution- documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class) states that the default max_concurrent_requests is 8.

Comment: @georgerw on my configuration that setting was set to a higher value.

Comment: I currently have this configuration in my app.yaml, and I'm still seeing this error. However I think this could also be caused by not closing connections, or opening multiple connections in a request.

Comment: @Mark you are correct, and I actually realized that and created a middleware that automatically closes DB connections when requests are finished. I also configured MySQL to auto close stale connections after a few minutes.

Comment: If you limit the number of concurrent request for a task queue, what happens when that limit is reached? Does it fail, or does it wait until a connection can be made?